# How to update composer on windows?

Tags: windows, apache, composer-php

If I run composer then I get:

> Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is
>   recommended to update it by running
>   "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update" to get
>   the latest version

[image: composer UI]

However, if I run the command `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update` then the following window appears, which says that the file could not be opened:
[image: cannot open file]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

> php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update

Answer (score 9):

I just figured out that I could also just execute

```
composer selfupdate
```

or

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

try Also:
composer update
it should run

Answer (score 0):

I run the below commands and it worked for me, so my composer version is 1.10.20 to 2.0.9

1. `php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update`
2. `composer self-update --2`